# PyQt QListWidget opens in a new window if I add it from the new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

If I add QListItem to the QListWidget at start, everything is okay. But If I add this from a new thread (`threading`), it opens in a new window and the program crushes.
Here's the code of add element:

```
def addLog(self, text, sId=0, pId=0):
        if text == 'Button':
            listItem = QListWidgetItem()
            listWidget = QWidget()
            listLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            listText = QLabel('[' + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") + ']   ' + text)
            listButton = QPushButton('Button')
            listLayout.addWidget(listText)
            listLayout.addWidget(listButton)
            listWidget.setLayout(listLayout)
            listItem.setSizeHint(listWidget.sizeHint())

            self.ui.logEdit.addItem(listItem)
            self.ui.logEdit.setItemWidget(listItem, listWidget)
```

Here's the code where I start a new thread:

```
def start(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

Here's the code of a new thread:

```
def worker(self):
        self.addLog('Button', 1, 2) # opens in a new window so the program crushes
```

If I call addLog from anywhere it's okay, but if I call it from a new thread, the program crushes.

Comment: No widget should be created or updated directly on a thread other than the main one

Comment: How do I do what I want?

Comment: that is part of the design of Qt5, and therefore of PyQt5, read the following: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: So I need do this with the help of QThread?

Comment: **you should not create and can not widgets or GUI elements in another thread, either with threading or QThread**

Comment: So many widgets do you have to create that you want to resort to using threads? I think you are trying to do something unnecessary or you have a very bad design.

Comment: I need add one element to QListWidget. And I found how I do this

Comment: I tried to do this with the help of pyqtSignal() and it worked fine

Comment: What you have seen is not correct, add it directly and do not use threads.

Comment: I know but I run infinity loop, and if I do this in the main thread the program is gonna freezing, so I need a new thread. And in that infinity loop I have to add new element to the QListWidget

Comment: you can update the gui indirectly from a secondary thread with pyqtSignal but not create the widgets.

Comment: you do not have to add it to the secondary thread, just pass the information to the main thread, and create the widgets with the information in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I created `pyqtSignal()` and connected it to my function and call signal from a new thread. It worked for me